Limiting the state size in flink
I have a flink job with RMQ source, filters, window (Tumbling window fires every 2seconds and uses processing time), aggregate function, sink. RockDB state backend with incremental checkpoints is enabled (Every 10s checkpointing is happening with 5s pause between checkpoints.). After 5 days, checkpoints size is 196MB and state size or delta data is 191 MB.
With this shall i assume my state is growing resulting in increased checkpoints?
If yes, how can i control my state size.
I read that State size is limited to available disk space. Does it mean if i reduce the taskmanager pod memory (or set same as my flink process memory), state size will be in control??
I am  struggling with this increasing state size. Any help would really be appreciated.

Following is checkpoints size for a week,

PRD Environment:  Checkpoints are stored in EFS. Task manager (3 taskmanagers with 5 slots each. Each operator except source (parallelism of 1) is having parallelism of 15) & Jobmanager is running in Kubernetes (clustered environment).
Below is the alignment duration and start delay after job was ran for 1 day.


What's the historical trend of your state size? E.g. from a day ago vs. today.

Also, what durations are you using for your window size and your checkpoint interval?

Thanks kkrugler for the reply (your reply made my day :)).  I have updated the question.  Could you please help with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78851595/understanding-flinks-state-handling-in-rocksdb-statebackend.  <-- This i tested in my local VDI with has standalone flink setup in docker(single taskmanager with 5 slots & each operator is having parallelism of 1).

my key by () uses date. I am assuming based on each date and my state will grow. So, there are chances it will grow in unbounded way. Aggregate Function is stateless so I cant configure stateTTl there. I am using tumbling window there also no way to add stateTTL. 1.Do i need to convert my tumbling window to some rich functions to access states and clean them up? or 2. is there any way I can do that with out changing to rich functions?

My Flink job is something similar to following Example: I need to find sum of tip a taxi driver gets every 2s. For this, key by uses date, taxi driver ID, taxi driver's company. Date varies every 24hours, driverID and company names vary between minimum 1 to max 600 in a minute.  I can get max 10 unique events in a 2second window. I tried finding what could be the default checkpoint size/state for my load, but I'm not successful with that

Is it really a 2 second window, or is it that you want to generate updated results every 2 seconds for taxi driver X on date Y?

Why are you using incremental checkpoints? If you really have 2 second windows, then every 10 seconds your checkpoint will have completely different data, so I don't think you get any win from making it incremental.

Ya it is 2seconds. In that case, check point size should get stabilize right soon.?

What were your results when you disabled incremental checkpointing?

It is increasing even after disabling incremental checkpoints.Is it really a 2 second window, - ->Ya. All the events that comes in 2s are aggregated. In  one window i can get only maximum 10 unique events. TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(2),Time.seconds(1)) -->is this very small window and offset?. Could this create issue ?

Having a small window shouldn't matter

one more thing i am worrying about is keyBy. my key by () uses date. I am assuming based on each date  state can grow. for 16/8/2024, driver X and company Y can have one state. for new day it will become new state right (17/8/2024, driver X and company Y ). I was thinking over the period of time when compaction runs my old state  (16/8/2024, driver X and company Y ) will be cleared. Not sure if this happens, how can i verify this? and along im not sure how long i need to wait for it to happen

How exactly are you doing the keyBy()? And since you have a 2 second window, why do you need to key by date?

After all of the Q&A above, my best guess is that your state size is so small that RocksDB compaction isn't getting triggered. Assuming your TM heap size is set to a reasonable value, you should be able to test using the in-memory hash map state backend.

I will also check about changing to hash map state backend.

If i change following settings, then with disabled incremental checkpoints(and rocksDB statebackend) my state should get stabilized right? state.backend.rocksdb.writebuffer.size : 1MB state.backend.rocksdb.compaction.level.target-file-size-base:1MB state.backend.rocksdb.compaction.level.max-size-level-base: 4MB , but it is not happening. I see that few compaction had happend from rocksDB metrics viewer, But still size is increasing

If i go back to hash map state backend, theoretically my state (once not referenced) will be GC collected right?

Correct, you should see GC activity as unused state entries get collected. That GC can cause stalls if it's excessive, which is one of the drawbacks to using the hash map state backend (plus limits to max state size, as discussed).

After changing to hashamap state backend with managed memory as 0, My checkpoints size is constant. When load is not there, checkpoint size falls back to default size. Thanks kkrugler for the help. I will monitor the GC counts i didn't see any FGC so far only YGC was more .
