Understanding Flink's state handling in rocksDB statebackend
I have a flink job with Rabbitmq source,keyby, tumbling window and aggregator function, sink.
I’m using rockDB state backend along with incremental checkpoints. Every 10s checkpointing is happening with 5s pause between checkpoints.
Constant load with same keys I used for my test. I did same test 5 times.
Following is the result of same.

1.Why is checkpoint size is increasing for same keys/same load over a period of time? – Does it mean lot of managed memory or disk space still there and compaction didn’t trigger yet?
2.Full checkpoint size has reduced in between. Is it because of compaction?

I have also enabled rocks DB native metrics, It shows only pending compaction? Is there any property which will show completed compaction?

I am using default rocks DB configuration (Flink version used is 1.18).  So write buffer size is 64MB and l0 compaction will create a l1 file which will be of size 64MB.
What is the default multiplier value and also how many levels are totally available in flink's rocks DB.

Let's say before memtable is getting filled with my state (i.e before it becomes 64MB), if operator needs to take snapshot how is it handled? Will it copy inflight data as it is, before memtable is flushed to .sst files? Because I'm seeing only sometimes .sst files are present. Other times a file without extension is present in checkpoints directory. Why?

If I reduce my diskspace will compaction run often? If so how to decide how much we need for state storage?

what is state.backend.rocksdb.compaction.level.max-size-level-base ? document says The upper-bound of the total size of level base files in bytes. " + "The default value is '256MB'."But it is not clear for me. Is it lmax file sizes? Single lmax file size or complete lmax size?


Thanks in advance.

I assume you've read through and understand the checkpoint tuning page (https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/ops/state/large_state_tuning/). This includes verifying you don't have issues with time to first checkpoint barrier or alignment time, as you want those solved before moving on to the size of your state.

When you say "I did same test 5 times", were those completely fresh runs? Or were you starting from saved state?

My flink job was continuously running on that I ran same test 5 times. I will send X events to my source queue and wait till the response of sink operator, then noted the checkpoints size.After that I had resend same X events to source queue and wait for the output. Like this I did 5 times.

If your state size is in the 100s of KB, and incremental checkpoints aren't a big win (which I think is the case here), then I'd recommend using the FsStateBackend.

Initially we had hashmap backend , with that OOM Exception was coming. So we switched to rocksdb State backend. In fsStateBackend, State is kept in local disk of task manager pod, how will State size be in control?? compaction logic is not there. Who will take of clearing old state data??. windows clears it automatically would that be enough.??.

I am using flink18 version, in that there is no FsStateBackend, https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/ops/state/state_backends/. Why??.  i am sure still it will support  'FsStateBackend" may be for backward compatilibility.

This checkpoints analyzis i am doing in my local setup, but in prd my checkpoints size is increasing in MB's. every day 30 to 40 MB it increases. In that case, what state backend should would be better?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78839038/limiting-the-state-size-in-flink in this i have added start delay and alignment duration details. It looks fine. Pls let me know if i am missing something

If you got OOM exceptions with a state size of only 300-600Kb, then I think something else is off with your configuration...e.g. maybe your TaskManagers don't have a large enough heap.

Re FsStateBackend, that's the legacy name for HashMapStateBackend, sorry. See 1.18 documentation at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/ops/state/state_backends/#fsstatebackend
